# Is this constructor correct?

Tags: c++

I have two classes A and B, and in class A I have an member of type B:

```
class B {
    public:
        B(); //default constructor
};

class A {
    public:
        A(); //constructor
        B b;
};
```

This is the definition of class A's constructor:

```
A::A() : b()
{}
```

Here, I tried to initialize `b` using the initialization list. My question is, is this way to initialize `b` correct, or am I just creating another temporary object named `b` inside the constructor of A that has nothing to do with `A::b`?

Comment: Correct? Yes. Necessary? No.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is correct. However, since `b` is of class type, the default constructor will be called automatically if `b` isn't mentioned in `A::A`'s initialization list, so you don't need to mention it at all.

Answer (score 4):

This method will initialize the field `b` with the constructor `B::B()`.  It does not create a temporary local.

Note that in this particular case it's also unnecessary.  The default constructor generated for `A` will do this by itself.  There is nothing wrong with being explicit here, it's just unnecessary

Comment: if the constructor of A isn't the default one, then would calling `b()` inside the initialization list of that constructor still be necessary?

Comment: @Chin no, it would still be invoked

Comment: @Chin: The C++ language guarantees that for class members, one constructor or another is called as long as it has a default constructor.  (Types without a default constructor are still _initialized_, but potentially not to useful values.  `int`, `int[3]` and `std::array<int, 3>` are examples)

Comment: @MooingDuck, Depends what you mean by initialized. "To default initialize an object means... ...otherwise, no initialization is performed." Also, it gets a bit messy, but trivial default constructors can sometimes not be called, not that it would be noticeable. The standard actually makes it explicit that these objects are considered constructed even though a constructor was never called.

Comment: @chris: The §8.5/6 bit that some initialization is no initialization has always irked me; I wish they used two different words there to clarify.  But the types are _default_ initialized no matter what.  As for constructors, if you're referring to §3.8/1, that says their _lifetime_ has begun, but that only really applies to class members in incredibly rare situations as far as I can recall.

Comment: I was actually going for § 8.5/8: *then the object is zero-initialized and, if T has a non-trivial default constructor, default-initialized;* and *An object that is value-initialized is deemed to be constructed and thus subject to provisions of this
International Standard applying to “constructed” objects, objects “for which the constructor has completed,”
etc., even if no constructor is invoked for the object’s initialization.* For clarification, I'm also talking about C++11, since I'm pretty sure some of the text around this area changed from C++03.